# How to measure dispersion of a single point within a group of points

Tags: standard-deviation

Lets say you are given a set of $n$ points and for each one, you want to get a measure of dispersion of its closest $d$ points. So a point far away from others will have a large measure of dispersion while points in a cluster have a low measure of dispersion. Anyone know which statistic would be useful for this?

I feel like this is something similar to standard deviation but standard deviation uses an average instead of just that single element.

Would summing the distance differences between that single point and its $d$ closest points work?

Comment: Standard deviation uses a square-root of the average squared deviation.

Answer (score 1):

You could:

1. measure the average absolute distance for the $j^{\text{th}}$ observation $\left(\frac{\sum_{i \ne j}{|x_{j} - x_{i}|}}{n-1}\right)$
2. measure the total absolute distance for the $j^{\text{th}}$ observation $\left(\sum_{i \ne j}{|x_{j} - x_{i}|}\right)$
3. measure the average distance for the $j^{\text{th}}$ observation $\left(\frac{\sum_{i \ne j}{x_{j} - x_{i}}}{n-1}\right)$
4. measure the total distance for the $j^{\text{th}}$ observation $\left(\sum_{i \ne j}{x_{j} - x_{i}}\right)$

And probably do a lot of other things. However, you haven't told us *why* you want to such a measure, and as the different behaviors you will get from each of the above will have different ramifications, your motivation is important.

**Update:** If, for example you want to filter out points because they are too dispersed (based on some yet to be determined criterion), then you might simply examine *what happens to the total variance* (or standard deviation) *when you remove each point*.

Comment: Hello and thank you for this answer. I am trying to create a program that filters out points that are too scattered too much distance wise(how much is too much is something I'll figure out later). Thus I was thinking that it would be helpful to have a measurement of how dispersed each point's is in relation to the $d$ closest points from it.

Comment: The update, because it suggests a global solution to a local problem, does not seem like an appropriate procedure.  The question--if my reading of its references to "cluster" is correct--concerns assessing how far a point might be from its nearest neighbors *compared* to how far it is from all the other points.

Comment: @whuber Can you say a bit more? The motivation for MaximumMath's procedure is to create a filtered body of data. My reasoning in the update is based on attending to the properties of the resulting filtered data. Although, I do see that I ignored the clustering issue.

Comment: Alexis, I agree the situation is not entirely clear. To understand one plausible interpretation please imagine, if you will, a one-dimensional problem in which the data are $(0,1,2, 49,50,51, 75, 98,99,100)$, the distance is Euclidean, and $d$ is chosen to equal $2$. On this basis the local scatter around every point except $75$ is determined by two nearest-neighbor distances $(1,1)$ or $(1,2)$, whereas the scatter around $75$ is determined by distances $(23,24)$, which are very large in comparison. On that basis $75$ would be filtered out as a kind of isolated "inlier."

Comment: I see. While I am not sure I buy the (very cute) term "inlier", 75 in the example you give *would* be an *outlier* in a nearest neighbor metric. Hmm.... *hmmm*...